# Show previous selectlist value on validation error

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

I have created a dummy object 'Console' with 2 required fields (type and year) and a VisualForce page in which I set them using a select list. This is the current scenario:

1. Set type to 'PlayStation' leave year as 'None' then click save. I get an expected validation error (year is required).
2. Set type to 'None' and set year to '2001' then click save. I get an expected validation error (type is required). However, the selectlist for 'Type' is set to the previous value 'PlayStation' which is inconsistent with the error message.

How can I retain the value of 'None' which the user selected for consistency?

**VisualForce:**

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Console__c" extensions="ConsoleNewController" sideBar="true">
    <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Console__c.fields.Type__c.Label}" for="consoleTypeSelectList"/>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!Console__c.Type__c}" size="1" required="true" id="consoleTypeSelectList">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!consoleTypes}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Console__c.fields.Year__c.Label}" for="consoleYearSelectList"/>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!Console__c.Year__c}" size="1" required="true" id="consoleYearSelectList">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!consoleYears}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" status="status" id="saveButton"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="!cancel" id="cancelButton"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller:**

```java
public with sharing class ConsoleNewController
{
    public ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    private Console__c console;
    private List<SelectOption> consoleTypes { get; private set; }
    private List<SelectOption> consoleYears { get; private set; }

    public ConsoleNewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.standardController = controller;
        this.console = (Console__c) controller.getRecord();
        this.consoleTypes = getConsoleTypes();
        this.consoleYears = getConsoleYears();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getConsoleTypes()
    {
        List<String> types = new List<String> {'PlayStation', 'Xbox', 'Nintendo', 'Atari', 'Sega'};
        List<SelectOption> typelist = new List<SelectOption>();
        typelist.add(new SelectOption('', 'None'));

        for (String type : types)
        {
            typelist.add(new SelectOption(type, type));
        }

        return typelist;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getConsoleYears()
    {
        List<SelectOption> yearList = new List<SelectOption>();
        yearList.add(new SelectOption('', 'None'));

        for (Integer i = 2001; i < 2018; i++)
        {
            String value = String.valueOf(i);
            yearList.add(new SelectOption(value, value));
        }
        return yearList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently according to your code, during validation error, page is not properly rendering.

To retain the values during validation error, you need to add `rerender ="pageMessages"` on Save button. **That's it!**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" 
            action="{!save}" 
            status="status" 
            id="saveButton" 
            rerender ="pageMessages"/>
```

> **Result:**

1. Initially, Type was 'PlayStation' and Year was 'None', Validation error properly throwing.
2. After that, change Type to 'None' and Year to '2003'. Validation error and Type is retaining to 'None'. *It will not show 'PlayStation' which you were facing the issues.*

[image]